# How to make sure if global keyboard hook have been disconnected?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, security

I have used [Stephen Toubs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx)  version of global keyboard hook, using it in a WIN 7 environment.

It works fine for a moment, and then it just stops receiving keystrokes.

I have increased the timeout value in regedit but it still disconnects after some time.

So problem is, how do I detect if it have been disconnected and how do I set the hook to be active again?

Comment: There's no documented way to detect that you lost the hook.  You need to tackle this from the other end and keep your program responsive under all circumstances.  Move expensive code to a worker thread.

Comment: Thats exactly what i have done but its still disconnects sometimes for some reason =/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way of knowing (from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

> The hook procedure should process a message in less time than the data
>   entry specified in the LowLevelHooksTimeout value in the following
>   registry key: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop
>
> If the hook procedure times out, the system passes the message to the
>   next hook. However, on Windows 7 and later, the hook is silently
>   removed without being called. There is no way for the application to
>   know whether the hook is removed.

One way you can work around this is to keep the timestamp of last message received and use background timer to add new hook after some time has passed from previous message.

Also, to minimize this happening your hook handling method should only collect minimum required information and leave the actual processing of the data to another thread.

Comment: 1.) I have almost no code in the hook method, but it stills disconnects sometimes. 
2.) Do you mean to save a date value from when the last time the hook worked? And after "10" min or so , rehook? Just want to know if i understood u correct.

Comment: yes, this is exacly it. Rembmer that hooks require message loop and are delivered on UI thread, so even if your hook proc is quick, other parts of application may be using UI Thread and cause delays which will in turn cause hook to be removed.

Comment: Ok so i guess , the only way is to save the last pressed key date and check if it have passed to long time. Only problem is if the user is AFK, then i dont want to rehook all the time?

Comment: You can do a combination of last pressed key time that you record and GetLastInputInfo http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx Using these two you can then make slightly better decision on when to rehook.

Comment: Problem is that GetLastInputInfo is also triggering when user moving the mouse. If it was only triggered when user pressed a key , then problem solved but this wont do it =/ i can only guess in this scenario

Comment: true, but it seems like the only way to go if want to use hooks on windows 7 and later.

Comment: Yea i guess there really is no other way. One thing i can do is to start using Rawinput instead of global hook, have u tried that?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that before, but with mouse input only. It worked well and I did not have problems with it, although it is bit more complicated to code than hooks and there's much less documentation on how to do it from c# (a lot of p\invoke code)

Comment: I have searched a bit for raw input but havent find any good documentation, u think u can help me setup mouse or keyboard for raw input? Or just show me some code/link

Comment: Can't get anything now (I'm away), but drop me an email at jarek@squaredinfinity.com and I'll email you code later.

Comment: This was the answer to the my question, and i will go for using RawInput instead.

Answer (score 2):

This is a feature! here's the [description of the reason](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2010/10/14/global-hooks-getting-lost-on-windows-7.aspx).

Comment: I wonder if this isnt the way i have to go, to stop using global hooks and start using RawInput instead?

Comment: i don't know, but that is how it sounds.